# Can you use l2ping to perform an echo request to an BLE device?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, l2cap

If I'm not mistaken [l2ping](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/l2ping.8.html) is used to perform an L2CAP echo request to a connected BLE (Bluetooth low energy) peripheral (see l2ping [source code](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/tools/l2ping.c#L111)). It is working if I try to ping my Smartphone, but not if I try to ping a BLE peripheral.

Comment: L2CAP echo request is not supported for BLE. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Emil Thx for your comment! I'm trying to implement some kind of automatic Fuzzing Framework with Scapy / python. Before starting to implement my own L2CAP echo request I wanted to test different, existing tools.

I'm currently aiming for Bluetooth 4.2. I've read a huge part of  "vol 3: Part A (L2CAP)" and didn't find anything like "this part of L2CAP only exists in BR/EDR". That's why I thought the L2CAP part of the stack is identical for BR/EDR and BLE devices. Did I misread L2CAP?

Comment: You can pretty much forget everything you read about L2CAP in the Standard if you are going to use BLE ^^. As you can read in the SIGNALING PACKET FORMATS chapter, table 4.2, the CID 0x0001 refers to BD/EDR and 0x0005 refers to BLE. As you see, nothing is supported on BLE except conn param update and LE credit based channels. Kind of really the only thing of L2CAP that's used in BLE is the use of the 4byte header to differentiate between GATT and SMP and to be able to segment and reassemble packets. I don't understand why they didn't give it a different name in BLE or defined a new layer type.

Comment: Well on the plus side that means there isn't much to do on the L2CAP "layer" regarding fuzzing (BLE). Thank you very much! :)